# Joining single polygon data to multiple polygons (not spatial associated)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.4

I have a polgyon shapefile with about 25 survey data information. The survey polygons could be seen as point data. I would like to assign the data to a shapefile of about 50 large zonal polygons. The second zone polygon contains an ID column, an id for each zone. Each of the 25 surveys contains survey attributes for all of the 50 polygons. The survey data contains a value for each of the zones to which I will symbolize.

Can someone tell me how I can connect to two shapefiles?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you attempted to join using the Joins & Relates option from the layer context menu in ArcMap?  What happens when you try that?

Comment: Add a screenshot of your data

Comment: Screenshot is of the Polgyon data and survey data

Answer (score -1):

As long as you have a UniqueID set in place then you should be able to Join the two tables together with ease.

Creating a relationship between your two tables would be the best first step to take. You will want to create a simple, one-to-many relationship between your two tables. After creating the relationship then you will want to use the Join tool. I would suggest using the 'Join Field' or the 'Add Join' tools.

This link might help you out:

desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-too‌​lbox

This explains more in depth how to use the 'Join Field' tool, unlike 'Spatial Join', this tool only joins specified fields in the table.

Comment: I revised my answer to aim it more towards ArcGIS, rather than QGIS. @BERA

Comment: The data cannot be spatially joined. Several of the survey polygons overlap the larger polygons. They are also independent from each other.